# Where is the seam on a SCNSphere?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Check out this code:

```
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 10)
    sphereGeometry.isGeodesic = falsebetter
    let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = newImage
    sphereMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    sphereGeometry.materials = [sphereMaterial]
    sphere = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphere.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
```

`newImage` is 1440x720 (a number I picked out of a hat).

Ok, where does the left and right edge of `newImage` appear on the sphere? I would have thought it would be "north", but that does not seem to be the case. My image seems to be centered to the east, which would imply the seam is on the west. I can't seem to find any discussion of this in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnsphere#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNSphere/segmentCount).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to think of it is that if your image was a plate carrée / equirectangular map of the earth with 0º longitude at its centre then the seam would be the dateline.

So this

[image]
would look like this from a viewpoint (0,0, +ve)

[image]

Comment: The seam would be the dateline... ok so that is kind of what I expected. I guess I am loading my images incorrectly or rotating the sphere incorrectly. I'm seeing the center of the image - 0 long, to the east.

Comment: Just for completeness - the image shown has earth node of radius 1 positioned at <0,0,0>, no rotation, camera at <0,0,2.5>, light at <0, 100, 100>